# как скрыть картинку и вывести другую в fancybox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Не получается скрыть картинку в fancybox, документации не нашел, `document.getElementById(wheel).style = "display: none";` вот так не получается

Answer (score 0):

Если закрыть то `$.fancybox.close();`
Если скрыть одно фото из нескольких в галереи, то у нее есть параметр data-fancybox="gallery" просто попробуйте удалить data атрибут

```
document.getElementById(wheel).removeAttribute(fancybox)
```

а новой добавить

```
document.getElementById(wheel).dataset.fancybox = "gallery"
```

Comment: мне нужно скрыть картинку которая находится в popupe, и вывести другую